# Bash script, read ends the script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "one"
read host
echo "two"
read ip
echo "three"
read oid
read oid
echo $oid $host >> logger.txt
```

it never makes it to echoing "two"

No matter if I pass parameters (this is to receive SNMP traps, and the parameters come) manually in any varied way.

EDIT: This has permissions etc etc, I am testing it by launching it manually, "one" is echoed.

Comment: `read` reads from standard input, and it blocks until it receives that input; so by "ends", do you mean "hangs"?

Comment: Are you trying to act on parameters passed to the script like so? - `yourscript.sh HOST_NAME IP OID OID`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` waits for input from STDIN.

If you do not insert any input by hand (in a interactive terminal) or you do not provide any input from STDIN like this:

```
echo -e "my_host\n192.168.1.100\nfoo\nbar" | ./myscript
```

it will hang waiting for input

In the example `\n` is a newline.

If you want to access parameters, do not use `read`, but the $1...$n variable.

```
./myscript my_host 192.168.1.100 foo
```

You need this:

```
#!/bin/sh
host=$1
ip=$2
oid=$3
echo $oid $host >> logger.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that explained where I was messing up in the CLI for passing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

read actually waits for user input.
`read host` will wait for a user to enter any data till he presses the return key and what ever the data user enters will be stored in host.